# Вопрос по JS. Хочу убрать event.target

Tags: javascript, dom

Событие происходит, если клик или наведение происходит над карточкой (class="cards).

```
<div onmouseover="animationCard(event); return false;" onclick="animationCard(event); return false;" class="cards card_delivery">
<input type="checkbox" id="main_delivery">
<label for="main_delivery">
       <img class="car card_img" src="image/delivery.png" alt="Бесплатная доставка">
</label>
<h2>lkerfvevrek</h2>
<p>/p>
<p></p>
 </div>


        <div onmouseover="animationCard(event); return false;" onclick="animationCard(event); return false;" class="cards card_tools">   
            <input type="checkbox" id="main_tools">
            <label  for="main_tools">
                <img class="tool card_img" src="image/tools.png" alt="Техническое обслуживание">
            </label>
            <h2>Техническая поддержка</h2>
            <p>Гарантия 1 год</p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
```

Вот как это карявенько реализовано:

function animationCard(event){
    if (busy){return;}

```
var cards = document.body.getElementsByClassName('cards');
var img = document.body.getElementsByClassName('card_img');
currentCount++;
alert(this.tagName);


for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
    if (img[i] == event.target || cards[i] == event.target || cards[i].children[1] == event.target || event.target == cards[i].children[2] || event.target == cards[i].children[3] ||  event.target == cards[i].children[4]){

        img[i].style.animationPlayState = 'running';
         busy = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            busy = false;
        }, 100)
        setTimeout(function(){
                img[i].style.animationPlayState = '';
                img[i].style.animationIterationCount = currentCount;
            }, 1000);
        break;  
    }

}
```

}

У меня ВОПРОС. Как мне избавится от проверки в цикле, типа:

```
if (img[i] == event.target || cards[i] == event.target || 
cards[i].children[1] == event.target || event.target == cards[i].children[2] 
|| event.target == cards[i].children[3] ||  event.target == 
cards[i].children[4])
```

И вместо всего этого я хочу проверять :

```
(cards[i].className == this.className)
```

Но this.className возвращает undefined.
Почему?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onmouseover="animationCard(this); return false;"
         onclick="animationCard(this); return false;" class="cards card_delivery">

function animationCard(card) { 
  if (busy) 
    return;

  var img = card.querySelector('.card_img');
  currentCount++;

  img.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
  ...
```